# Does Blazemeter results are correct comparing with JMeter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

Recently I ran a same JMX script in JMeter and also in Blazemeter, I found that Blazemeter results are showing like **300ms** , while JMeter showing like **1200ms**. I am confused which tool is correct. At first, I don't understand why there is so much differnce in results and which tool should I believe?

Answer (score 2):

BlazeMeter cannot report results which differ from JMeter because **BlazeMeter is using JMeter** under the hood.

Response time itself doesn't tell the full story, one of possible reasons I can think of is **Latency**.

For example if you're located in North Korea and testing an application which is hosted in South Africa it will take some time for packets to travel across the globe back and forth.

Given the following formula:

```
Elapsed time = Connect Time + Latency + TTLB
```

If you remove i.e. Connect Time you should see more "clear" results.

More information:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [How to Analyze the Results of a Load Test Using BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0/)